# Login into a Website via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to login into a website via powershell ISE. The Web page comes up but it doesn't enter the credentials.

```
 $username = "DSmith" 
 $password = "Password123" 

 $ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 

 $ie.visible=$false

 $ie.navigate("https://feedback.camdenccg.nhs.uk/acl_users/credentials_cookie_auth/require_login?    came_from=https%3A//feedback.camdenccg.nhs.uk/james-wigg-and-queens-crescent-practices/4ef32a4e/download_responses%3Foverride-query%3DTrue") 

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 

$ie.document.getElementById('__ac_name').value= "$username" 

$ie.document.getElementById('__ac_password').value = "$password" 

$ie.document.getElementById("loginform").submit()

start-sleep 5
```

The Error I get is:

```
   The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))
   At line:10 char:7
   + while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
   +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
   At line:12 char:1
   + $ie.document.getElementById('__ac_name').value= "$username"
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Are you sure `__ac_name` is the correct ID?

Comment: `$test = $ie.document.getElementById("loginform")` then 
`Get-Variable $test`will return `null`, indicating that there is no object on the page with ID 'loginform", so you can't click it. Confirm the object names and try using `getElementByTagName` or `getElementsByType("button") | where { $.Name -eq "loginform" }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the tag name to set the value and then use the input value to do the clicking. (note: there are other ways of accomplishing this , I'm just giving you an example)

```
$username = "your user name" 
$password = "your pass word" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true


checkUrlStatusOk -endpoint $rabbitMQEndpoint

$ie.navigate("https://feedback.camdenccg.nhs.uk/acl_users/credentials_cookie_auth/require_login?    came_from=https%3A//feedback.camdenccg.nhs.uk/james-wigg-and-queens-crescent-practices/4ef32a4e/download_responses%3Foverride-query%3DTrue") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 

$userField = $ie.document.getElementsByName("__ac_name")
@($userField)[0].value =$username

$passField = $ie.document.getElementsByName("__ac_password")
@($passField)[0].value =$password


#login submit
$loginButton = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input") 
Foreach($element in $loginButton )
    {
    if($element.value -eq "Log In"){

    Write-Host $element.click()
    }

    }

Start-Sleep 10
```